# How to replace container class in react-bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I've installed react-bootstrap, and have proven I can use the grid components which is my primary need.  But why is "Container" not found, and how should I wrap my outermost content so that my page has margins and whatever else is normally set by bootstrap?

I understand that I can use regular CSS, but (a) wouldn't a Container be cleaner to match the bootstrap within, and (b) what else should be there, beside margins, to wrap all the inner stuff and still have it work well?

Comment: Have a look to the [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/layout/) lib, they have this `Container` component you are looking for. Else just use the `container` CSS class

Comment: @soywod, thanks for the suggestion.  I'll check out reactstrap, but can you explain more about the CSS container class?  Where it's defined and how I apply it in JSX?

Comment: `react-bootstrap` and `reactstrap` both need to have bootstrap lib imported (the CSS one, for eg [this cdn](https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/)). Then you just have to add the `container` class as described in [the official doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container). Something like : `<div className="container"> ... </div>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can :

- Use the [reactstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) lib that contains this `Container` comp you are looking for
- Use the bootstrap `container` CSS class :

`<div className="container"> ... </div>`

In both case, a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/bootstrap/css/lib">` will be required to get this working.

Answer (score 3):

React bootstrap actually does have a "container". Its the **Grid** component.

When you apply the *fluid* property to it, it makes the 'container' span the width of your monitor. Then as usual you would apply a *Row* component from react-bootstrap (which is basically the `<div class="row"></div>` component) and underneath that you would then apply the *Col* component also from react-bootstrap (which is basically the `<div class="col-md-4"></div>` etc html component.

If you don't want to apply a width to the grid container the size of the monitor you can simply just not include the *fluid* property to it and it will work just like a normal div container.

The grid follows the same 12-column rule like regular bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
<Grid bsClass="container">
...
</Grid>
```

In addition to `react-bootstrap` you can also include the `Bootstrap CSS` in your project by running:

1. Install bootstrap npm module

   ```
   npm install --save bootstrap@latest
   ```
2. Import the CSS by

   ```
   import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
   ```

   in your app's root component. If you use `create-react-app` you can use the`index.js` file for that.
3. Now you can use all Bootstrap classes in your project like so

   ```
   <div className="container"></div>
   ```

   or

   ```
   <Grid className="container"></Grid>
   ```